# Understanding the behavior of gcloud sql export sql and subsequent import

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I've got a Google Cloud SQL instance and, for a purpose of mine, I decided to create a sort of replica. To achieve this, I decided to export the database of my instance, create a second one and import the exported backup of the first instance into the second instance.

Before begin, I checked to the used storage size and I saw it was about 125GB. Then I exported the database using the following command:

```
gcloud sql export sql MY_INSTANCE gs://MY_BUCKET/2018-10-17/mysql/MY_DB.mysql.sql.gz --database=MY_DB
```

When it finished, as I said, I imported that backup into the "replica instance", and... surprise! The used storage size was 180GB!

How is that possible? Why the "replica instance" uses 55GB more than the first one?

Thank in advance to those who will answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation for this is the "bin_log" sizes. It does count into the disk size after the import.

To see if you **data** itself is the same size I recommend running:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024, 1) "DB Size in GB"
FROM
  information_schema.tables;
```

On *both* instances and  comparing sizes to have a more accurate measurement.

You can check also the size of your Binary Logs by running: `SHOW BINARY LOGS;` also in *both* instances, do the sum up and see if that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Sorry for late response @gabidavila, I confirm the bin_log is enabled on both machines but I don't know their dimension. I want to report something strage happened this morning (it can be correlated): at (about) 7:55 (hour of Rome) the used storage size suddenly get down from 186GB to 109GB. I really can't image why. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdrd0.png

Comment: Cloud SQL retains binary log for one week. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups).